# Biased random number generation

Tags: c++, math

I want to generate random integers from -1 to some value k. But I want to do it in a fashion that the probability of getting a -1 is above 70%. For example:-
-1 2 -1 -1 6 -1 -1.
I am doing this to test my code against a brute force approach.

Comment: And your question actually is?

Comment: Check what you can do with https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: You can read the question here https://www.codechef.com/LTIME75B/problems/TRIP2.  Contest is over so you should not face any problem in answering. Also the question has nothing to do with random numbers I just want to debug my code against setters code, that's it.

Comment: Create an array (or standard container) containing the values from `-1` to `k`.   Replicate the value of `-1` enough times so it accounts for 70% of the total number of elements in the array.   Use the standard library algorithm `std::shuffle()` to shuffle the array, and pick values in order.    Whenever you've picked all values from the array (i.e. the number of values picked exceeds the number of values in the array) shuffle again before picking values.

Comment: @Peter Thanks! for the approach.

Comment: You're probably getting downvotes because the question is "How do I write this code?" rather than "What is wrong with this code I wrote?" Don't take it personally; we all get downvoted eventually, whether we deserve it or not.

Comment: Indeed - don't take it personally and lash out. The fact is that you posted a question that shows no research effort or attempt to solve the problem yourself, yet we are not here giving our free time to "do it for you"! If you hover your mouse over the downvote button you'll see this. Cheers.

Comment: @Peter Post your answer down below where it can undergo the proper peer review

Comment: Your text does not indicate if zeroes are OK from your generator or not. From the problem page it seems these are not OK.

Answer (score 2):

This should do. If you generate a random number between 0 and 100 and it's less than the probability (in this case n), then getProb returns true and you have your -1.
Otherwise, just generate another random number modulo k

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

bool getProb(int n) {
    return (rand() % 101) < n;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int probab = 75;
    int k = 10;
    vector<int> res;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (getProb(probab)) res.push_back(-1);
        else res.push_back(rand() % k);
    }
}
```

Comment: `<random>` would be better, but otherwise this is what I thought too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short way of doing it using `<random>`.

```
#include <random>

int biased_rand(int k, int prob)
{
    static std::random_device rd;
    static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist_prob(0, 100);

    if (dist_prob(rd) <= prob)
        return -1;

    return std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0, k)(rd);
}
```